# Tool to search Facebook status'

Tags: facebook, search

I'm looking for a tool to search for Facebook status' that I have previously posted.

Vital Features:

- Should be able to search an account that has posts going years back
- Should be able to search for quotes

Nice to have:

- Ability to search for status's posted by my friends
- Ability to search for status's that I've commented on

Answer (score 3):

[F-search](https://apps.facebook.com/f-search-app/) is a Facebook App that searches notes, links and recent status'. It allows you to search both for status' that you've posted and status' that your friends have posted. I don't know how far back it goes though.

Comment: No longer working.